# removeEventListener for beforeunload handled after submit in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been asked to implement a feature  ...

1. Webpage has it's "action" buttons disabled until a form element is changed.
2. Webpage issues a warning message when a user initiates and event that would leave the page while there are unsaved changes.
3. Clicking the submit button, after it's enabled, should submit like normal (it should not display the popup warning)

Here is an example of the code used in the solution.  The `hasChanged` variable is what controls whether or not the page can be reloaded with or without a message.  The variable doesn't seem to get updated before the window is unloaded in FF and IE, but does in Chrome.

The inline submit call was already there.  I'm not sure why - that portion was inherited:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="http://www.google.com">
<textarea class="watch" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</form>
<br><br>
<div class="submit disabled">
<a class="" href="#" onclick="$('#form').submit();$(this).text('saving...');">Submit</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var hasChanged=false;
$('textarea.watch').on('keyup change', function(){
    hasChanged = true;
    $('.submit').removeClass('disabled');
});
$('.submit a').click(function() {
    hasChanged = false;
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload');
});
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    var confirmationMessage = 'You have unsaved changes.';
    if (hasChanged) {
        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
        return confirmationMessage;
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.disabled a {
    pointer-events: none;
    color:#aaa;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

I've tried to unbind beforeunload on the "Submit" button before the submit function is called, but that didn't seem to work:

```
<a class="" href="#" onclick="$(window).unbind('beforeunload');('#form').submit();$(this).text('saving...');">Submit</a>
```

Issue in action (open in Chrome, then Firefox/IE):  [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Gzs/13/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably because you have inline `onClick` logic that gets executed in different order in FF/Chrome. There is also across-origin error with posting a form to google, and it can behave differently in browsers.

Also, you don’t need to unbind the event, the `hasChanged` variable is supposed to take care of that (if I understand the logic correctly). And if you unbind the event, you need to bring in the function as argument (see the other answer).

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L4Gzs/15/

```
$('.submit a').click(function() {
    hasChanged = false;
    $('#form').submit();
    $(this).text('saving...');
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  The posting to google was just for demo (first url I thought of.)  I see that this works in the fiddle, however, it's made things worse in the actual implementation.  Now both Chrome and FF are displaying the warning message on submit.  I'm continuing to look through the code (all inherited.)

Comment: This IS the correct answer, although there is some other code in this project that is preventing it from working.  I'm accepting it.